# Python list to dict with multiple values for each key

Tags: python

Can the list

```
mylist = ['a',1,2,'b',3,4,'c',5,6]
```

be used to create the dict

```
mydict = {'a':(1,2),'b':(3,4),'c':(5,6)}
```

Comment: Yes sure. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I would start by reconsidering whether the list needs to exist in the first place. Could you redesign the code that builds the list to build the dictionary instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> mylist = ['a',1,2,'b',3,4,'c',5,6]
>>> 
>>> v = iter(mylist)
>>> mydict = {s: (next(v),next(v)) for s in v}
>>> mydict
{'a': (1, 2), 'c': (5, 6), 'b': (3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have some kind of criteria which ones are the keys. If the strings are the keys then:

```
d = {}
key = None
for item in my_list:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        key = item
    else:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict((x, (y, z)) for (x, y, z) in zip(*[iter(['a',1,2,'b',3,4,'c',5,6])]*3)) 
{'a': (1, 2), 'c': (5, 6), 'b': (3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['a',1,2,'b',3,4,'c',5,6]

mydict = {}

for i in range(len(mylist))[::3]:

    mydict[mylist[i]] = (mylist[i+1],mylist[i+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but your mydict should be created with quotation marks surrounding strings, and square brackets around your list:

```
mydict = {"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4],"c":[5,6]}
```

Otherwise, if you're looking to use that list to programmatically create your dictionary:

```
mydict = {}
i = 0
while i < len(mylist):
    mydict[mylist[i]] = [mylist[i+1], mylist[i+2]]
    i = i + 3
```